# VSCode から yarn コマンドを実行しても "操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません" と表示されてしまう

Tags: vscode, yarn

Webpack Dev Server を起動するため Visual Studio Code のターミナルで `yarn start` を実行しても以下のエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいます。
どのような対応をすればいいでしょうか。

```
yarn : 用語 'yarn' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述され
ていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ yarn start
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (yarn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

OSはどれでしょうか。

> 'yarn' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述され
> ていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。

おそらく上記エラーメッセージからWindowsと推察します。

vscodeのターミナルは、特に設定を調整していなければcmdを起動しているだけです。
（cmdを開くかpowershellを開くかは設定で変更できます。）
なので、エラーメッセージの原因は、概ね普通にcmdを使用する場合と同様です。
特定のコマンド＝exeが見つからないのであれば、そのexeにPATHが通っていません。

追記・要約

1. まず、Windowsにおいて、コマンド≒exeのことです。
   コマンドを実行する≒exeをダブルクリックと思ってください。
2. 「PATHを通す」とは、CUI（コマンドプロンプト(cmd)やpowershellの総称）でコマンドを実行しようとする際、コマンドを探すフォルダを追加することです。
   PATHを通すことで、フォルダーパスを含めたフルパスを入力することなくそのコマンドを実行できるようにします。
3. パスを追加するには、以下に、フォルダーパスを追加します。
   コントロールパネル > システム > システム詳細設定 > 環境変数 > システム環境変数 > Path
   ※ 「PATH 通す」でggった方が丁寧に説明しているサイトが多いと思います。
4. ユーザ環境変数とシステム環境変数の違いは、OSにログインしたユーザーごとに別の設定にするか、ユーザに関わらず適用するかの違いです。

yarnコマンド（exe）自体がどこにあるかは、yarn自体をどうインストールしたかによるかと思います。

Comment: OSはWindows10です。
PATHを通すにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: @user25636 追記しました

Answer (score 0):

Node.JSをインストールしてPATHを通すと、yarnコマンドが使えるようになります。

C:> where yarn
C:\opt\nodejs\yarn
C:\opt\nodejs\yarn.cmd

PS C:> yarn -v
1.22.17

Comment: これで試しましたが使えるようにはなりませんでした。